# Помощь с событиями С#

Tags: c#, события

Мне нужно передать событие с одной формы в другую. Событие - конец записи голоса (оно типа **void**). В **Program.cs** создаю класс.

```
static class SRec
{
public static void Val {get; set;}
}
```

В форме, где у меня заканчивается запись, я пишу

```
SRec.Val = wavein.StopRecording();
```

Выдает ошибку: " **Cannot implicity convert type "void" to "void"** "

Мне это нужно для того, что бы форме два в if было прописано, как только запись закончилась, то запустить таймер. Что то вроде этого:

```
if(SRec.Val = wavein.StopRecording())
{
timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Тут нет событий, но советуют сделать через события. Как это сделать? 
Как правильно передать конец записи в другую форму? Спасибо!

Comment: wavein - это что? это объект из naudio? если так, то у него есть событие завершения.

Answer (score 1):

> как только запись закончилась, то запустить таймер.

Если wavein - это объект из NAudio, то есть событие завершение записи. В обработчике этого события можно запустить таймер.

```
var w = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
w.RecordingStopped += (s, e) => {
    // тут код для запуска таймера ...
};
w.StartRecording();
```

---

Если надо открыть вторую форму, в ней что-то показать/сделать и после завершения уведомить первую форму, то надо во второй форме определить событие, на которое подписывается первая форма.
Ниже пример. На Form1 есть кнопка. Если ее нажать, то открывается Form2, в которой в отдельном потоке что-то делается. После завершения работы, посылается событие.

```
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            new Button() { Parent = this, Text = "Start" }
                .Click += (s, e) => {
                    var f2 = new Form2();
                    f2.Stopped += delegate { f2.Close(); };
                    f2.Start();
                };
        }
    }

    class Form2 : Form {
        public event EventHandler Stopped = delegate { };
        public void Start() {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();   // долго что-то делается
            })
            .ContinueWith(t => {
                Stopped(this, EventArgs.Empty);    // посылаем событие
            }
            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            this.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно.Попробую сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Наверно, формы друг о друге ничего знать не должны - это раз. В духе MVP это будет примерно так: 1 форма реализует интерфейс с событием `StopRecord` и, соответственно, Presenter (или у вас где-то в Program.cs) на это событие есть подписка. 2 форма имеет какой-то метод (тоже через интерфейс, наверно) типа `StartTimer`. Ну и в Presenter-e (читай в Program.cs у вас) обработчик события `StopRecord` первой формы дернет `StartTimer` второй формы. Как-то так.